# error TS5083: Cannot read file node_modules/gts/tsconfig-google.json when installing angular cli on Mac

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, npm-install

I am running `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli`, and I am running in to a bunch of errors.

The latest one is this:

```
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@2.0.1: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm ERR! code 2
npm ERR! git dep preparation failed
npm ERR! command /opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/20.0.0/bin/node /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js install --force --cache=~/.npm --prefer-offline=false --prefer-online=false --offline=false --no-progress --no-save --no-audit --include=dev --include=peer --include=optional --no-package-lock-only --no-dry-run
npm ERR! npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm ERR! npm ERR! code 2
npm ERR! npm ERR! path ~/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clonecrQU0L
npm ERR! npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! npm ERR! command sh -c npm run compile
npm ERR! npm ERR! > cliui@8.0.1 precompile
npm ERR! npm ERR! > rimraf build
npm ERR! npm ERR! 
npm ERR! npm ERR! 
npm ERR! npm ERR! > cliui@8.0.1 compile
npm ERR! npm ERR! > tsc
npm ERR! npm ERR! 
npm ERR! npm ERR! error TS5083: Cannot read file '~/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clonecrQU0L/node_modules/gts/tsconfig-google.json'.
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: ~/.npm/_logs/2023-05-01T22_18_21_178Z-debug-0.log

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: ~/.npm/_logs/2023-05-01T22_18_10_638Z-debug-0.log
```

How do I fix this and successfully install angular CLI on my Mac?

Answer (score 0):

Weird, I started getting this error today also and it's stopping my CI run.  It seems someone opened a [related(?) issue on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/25110) that may resolve this one.  Hopefully we'll see a fix soon.

Answer (score 0):

I too was getting this error yesterday. I spent a bit of time struggling to find out why. However, it seems to be transient issue, I was able to do a basic `npm install -g @angular/cli` today without any problems.